# django localsettings.py giving me error on moving from one localhost to another

Tags: django

I had my website running in  django local environment and it was working fine.... But for some reasons i have used localsettings.py file from another localhost system runnig same website... It started giving me 505 error... and when i traced back... following things started appering ....

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
        self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
        return self.application(environ, start_response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
        self.load_middleware()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 51, in load_middleware
        raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Middleware module "%s" does not define a "%s" class' % (mw_module, mw_classname))
    ImproperlyConfigured: Middleware module "django.middleware.csrf" does not define a "CsrfResponseMiddleware" class
    [05/Sep/2012 15:33:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Any help would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CsrfResponseMiddleware` was removed in Django 1.4. You're probably running Django 1.2-1.3 in one environment and Django 1.4-master in the other.

Comment: hi there i got the answer, I was actually in 1.4 so when i commented out                                     #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',                                  It started working fine... Thanks for the help